# Error applying security access is denied

Tags: windows-7, iis

I have a directory, c:\MySite2, that sometimes is used as the location for an IIS Web application, although currently IIS is configured to point the application to a different directory (different version of the website).  At any rate, my website's application pool is runs under the Network Service account, and so I tried adding that account to the directory c:\MySite2.

I right-clicked on the C:\MySite2 folder in Windows Explorer, chose properties, and tried to give Network Service full control.  When I do this I'm getting errors like:

```
Error Applying Security

C:\MySite2\MyPage.aspx

Access is denied.
```

and

```
Error Applying Security

C:\MySite2\SomeXML.xml

Access is denied.
```

Etc. My domain account is an administrator on the machine and like I said the IIS web application is currently not even pointing to C:\MySite2.  Any idea why I'm getting these messages and what I can do about them?

-Eric

Comment: Maybe there's an automatic procedure in the iis that removes all "unnecessary" permissions.
Can you test it on a new (and properly configured) folder?

Comment: How would that work if IIS isn't using the folder for anything when I'm setting the permissions?

Comment: I meant create the folder, config the permissions, fill up the folder with a website, and point your iis to that folder.